# C# WinForms using FlashLight built-in into mobile device running Windows 10 Professional x64

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, camera

I've created a WinForms (C#) application and I have to add support for the built-in flash. The device is Tablet PC running x64 architecture Windows 10 Professional (common Windows 10). Is there any way to do that? My application captures video from a built-in camera - I'm using OpenCV Sharp to do that, but I can't find any possibility to use a built-in flashlight. I need just manually turn on and off the light. I've found a lot of examples but it is possible only through UWP which I can't add to WinForms in any way.
Does anyone know the way to use the built-in flashlight in WinForms Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows API can be used in any non-UWP-C#-project by adding [UwpDesktog](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/archive/blogs/lucian/how-to-call-uwp-apis-from-a-desktop-vbc-app) NuGet Package
and adding these references:

> ```
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\References\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\UnionMetadata\Facade\Windows.WinMD
> c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
> ```

Then you can [turn on flashlight using MediaCaptur from UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845600/how-can-i-create-flashlight-app-in-uwp-c-sharp).